# Show that no number of the form 10...014 is evenly divisible by 7

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Number theory question. Not sure how to approach this one, does the ... mean 0s or any number?

Comment: I assume it means $0's$.  Under that assumption, Hint:  such a number is of the form $10^n+14$ for some $n$.

Comment: I assume the dots mean zeros. Then if $10\ldots014$ were divisible by $7$, then $10\ldots 000$ would also be divisible by $7$. Does that seem right? (Maybe think prime factorization?)

Comment: Just to say:  $105014$ is divisible by $7$, so the dots can't represent "any number".

Comment: $$10^k+14\equiv 0\pmod{7}\quad\Longrightarrow\quad 3^k\equiv 0\pmod{7}$$

Answer (score 5):

This number is of the form $10^n + 14$ (for $n \ge 4$).  Of course 7 divides 14, but $7$ does not divide $10^n$, whose prime factorization is $2^n 5^n$.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $100 \ldots 014$ is divisible by $7$, then so is $100\ldots 014 - (2 \times 7) = 100\ldots 014 - 14 = 100 \ldots 000$. However, the only prime factors of $100 \ldots 000$ are $2,5$ (it is $10^1$ for some $n > 0$), hence $7$ does not divide this number, giving a contradiction.

I do not see any other meaning of the $\ldots$ in the question. The $...$ cannot mean something arbitrary : for example $105014$ as given above.